# How to Let User Choose Number of Rows and Columns in Connect Four Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've completed a Connect 4 game but I want the user to be able to choose the number of rows and columns. Could somebody help me with that? Here is my code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/iwitecuxum.py Thank you so much! The board can be found under main() and display_board(board)

```
def main():
    """The Main Game Loop:"""

    free_cells = 42
    users_turn = True
    ttt_board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

    while not winner(ttt_board) and (free_cells > 0):
        display_board(ttt_board)
        if users_turn:
            ttt_board = make_user_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        else:
            ttt_board = make_computer_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        free_cells -= 1

    display_board(ttt_board)
    if (winner(ttt_board) == 'X'):
        print("Y O U   W O N !")
    elif (winner(ttt_board) == 'O'):
        print("T H E   C O M P U T E R   W O N !")
    else:
        print("S T A L E M A T E !")
    print("\n*** GAME OVER ***\n")
```

and board

```
def display_board(board):
    """This function accepts the Connect Four board as a parameter.
    It will print the Connect Four board grid (using ASCII characters)
    and show the positions of any X's and O's.  It also displays
    the column numbers on top of the board to help
    the user figure out the coordinates of their next move.
    This function does not return anything."""

    print(" 0   1   2   3   4   5   6")
    for row in board:
        print(" " + " | ".join(row))
        print("---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to *input* those numbers, or how to modify your program to *use* them?

Comment: I want the user to specify the row and column

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.